# Should LAPACK dgetrf inputs and outputs be transposed?

Tags: c, lapack, blas, atlas

I'm calling `dgetrf` from LAPACK on a row-major matrix, via `clapack.h`.

I have the matrix `A = [4,9,2; 3,5,7; 8,1,6]`.

If I call dgetrf, the result is `[9.0, 0.222222, 0.444444; 5.0, 5.888888, 0.132075; 1.0, 5.777777, 6.792453]`. However, the result *should* be `[8.0, 1.0, 6.0; 0.5, 8.5, -1.0; 0.375, 0.544118, 5.294118]`.

If I instead transpose A prior to calling `dgetrf`, and then transpose the output once more, I get the correct result.

The call I'm using is: `clapack_dgetrf(CblasRowMajor, 3, 3, A, 3, ipiv);` `ipiv` is, of course, an integer array of size 3, and A is an array of doubles, size 9: `[4,9,2,3,5,7,8,1,6]`.

I've tried switching the order argument to `CblasColMajor`, just in case I'm crazy, and that doesn't work as expected either.

Is this as it should be?